When did the Swaymvar system stop?
So as we know the scriptures talk about the swayamwara system being common during the Ramayan and Mahabharat era. When did this stop being practised?

I’m voting to close this question because it is question appropriate for History

Svayaṁvara prathā is for rājakumārīs (princesses), not for ordinary women. Plus, in svayaṁvara, normatively Rājās and rājakumāras are invited as potential suitors. In current-day India, there are sparsely any rājakumārīs, and royal suitors (potential) for them. Also, it's important to note, that although svayaṁvara prathā is no longer happening, still it's not like there aren't women today, who choose their own vara. On the other hand, compared to the olden days, it seems that nowadays more women choose their own vara.

Good question. I always thought it was a beautiful custom, but to my knowledge there has never been a historical account of a Swayamvar outside of scripture. I can say for sure that it has not happened since 1995 when match.com went online.

how about shaadi.com? :-) @Sanjeev
